# SwiftUI: Parse JSON and create dynamic list

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to parse/decode a JSON **string** and then create a dynamic list.

Example JSON:
`[{"course":"course1","teacher":"teacherName1"},{"course":"course1","teacher":"teacherName2"}]`

My wish:

```
List {
  HStack {
    Text("course1")
    Spacer()
    Text("teacherName1")
  }
  HStack {
    Text("course2")
    Spacer()
    Text("teacherName2")
  }
}
```

I've tried it with JSONDecoder() and arrays but Xcode marks my TabView over and over with this message: `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Binding<_>?'`

I'm new to swift, sorry ;)

Comment: show us, what did you try! How could somebody to help you with your code, if it is not part of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an example that you can follow:

```swift
import SwiftUI

let jsonString = """
[{"course":"course1","teacher":"teacherName1"},{"course":"course1","teacher":"teacherName2"}]
"""

let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()


struct Course: Codable, Identifiable {

    let id = UUID()
    let course: String
    let teacher: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let courses: [Course] = (try? JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)) ?? []

    var body: some View {
        List(courses) { course in
            HStack {
                Text(course.course)
                Spacer()
                Text(course.teacher)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made the `Course` struct confirm to `Identifiable` as well as `Codable` so that the `List` can iterate over the array of courses. Also I defaulted to empty `Data` and empty courses array in case decoding fails. You could write better error handling here depending on your needs.